# Javascript Object inserting data without destroying

Tags: javascript, object

So let's say I have four components, three children and one parent.

```
parentObject = {}
childOneObject = {starTime, endTime}
childTwoObject = {color, theme, junk}
childThreeObject = {starsInSky, wheelsOnCar, shoesOnFeet}
```

The parentObject should be made up of all these values to submit in the end.

At the end of the first component, a user will submit their data and it will get added to the parentObject. Which looks like this

```
parentObject = childOneObject
```

The user will continue on to step two and submit their info which works the same as step one, but if I write
    parentObject = childTwoObject

The original data is obviously destroyed. **I'd like to know if there is a way to insert chunks of data into objects without destroying older data or having to target things line by line like**

```
parentObject.startTime = 5:00
```

I do not like to have to do this because it's cumbersome to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator. This operator will merge the child objects with parent object

```
const parentObject = {};
parentObject = { ...parentObject, ...childOneObject };
parentObject = { ...parentObject, ...childTwoObject };
parentObject = { ...parentObject, ...childThreeObject };
```

you can also do it in one step

```
const parentObject = {};
parentObject = { ...parentObject, ...childOneObj, ...childTwoObj, ...childThreeObj };
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) them all on-top-of the parent…

```js
let parentObject = {}
let childOneObject = {startTime: 0, endTime: 1}
let childTwoObject = {color: 'red', theme: 'dark', junk: true}
let childThreeObject = {starsInSky: Number.MAX_VALUE, wheelsOnCar: 4, shoesOnFeet: 2}

Object.assign(parentObject, childOneObject, childTwoObject, childThreeObject)

console.log(parentObject)
```

Comment: Upvoting for using `Number.MAX_VALUE` for `starsInSky`

Answer (score 1):

> It is very simple with the help of a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
// Inital  
parentObject = {}
```

```
//Step 1:
childOneObject = {starTime, endTime}
parentObject = {...childOneObject};
```

```
// Step 2
childTwoObject = {color, theme, junk}
parentObject = {...parentObject, ...childTwoObject}
```

```
// Step 3
childThreeObject = {starsInSky, wheelsOnCar, shoesOnFeet}
parentObject = {...parentObject, ...childThreeObject}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const parentObject = {}
const childOneObject = {starTime: 0, endTime: 1}
const childTwoObject = {color:'red', theme:'dark', junk:false}
const childThreeObject = {starsInSky:2, wheelsOnCar:4, shoesOnFeet:2}

const assignKeyVals = (parent, child) => {
   Object.entries(child).forEach(([key,val]) => parent[key] = val)
}

assignKeyVals(parentObject, childOneObject)
assignKeyVals(parentObject, childTwoObject)
assignKeyVals(parentObject, childThreeObject)

console.log(parentObject)
```